# running python selenium script from docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver

Basically I'm using the `selenium/standalone-chrome` image to run my python selenium script.

But I am getting `No module named pip` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'` in `python3`.

How comes selenium is not pre-installed? Do I need to install everything via Dockerfile or is there something I am missing ?

I also would like to know what is the default entrypoint for this image - which launches the grid UI and which I need to overwrite to run my script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

selenium/standalone-chrome contains chrome browser. Either you install packages needed by you or run your tests from another image and use remote driver.